# Show that the differential of a Liouville form is nondegenerate

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm stuck with the Problem 19.8 b) from Introduction to Manifolds from Loring W. Tu

The Questions is

> Prove that if $\lambda$ is the Liouville form on the total space $T^*M$ of the cotangent bundle of an
> $n$-dimensional manifold $M$, then $d λ$ is a nondegenerate 2-form on $T^∗M$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Let $\dim M = 2$ and let $\lambda = adx + bdy$ be the 1-form in local coordinates. Then we get $d\lambda = (\frac{\delta b}{\delta x} - \frac{\delta a}{\delta y})dx \wedge dy$. Now i need to show that it is nondegenerate.

Comment: If $\dim M=2$, $\dim T^*M=4$ so the Liouville form would be expressed as $\lambda_1 dx^1+\lambda_2dx^2+\lambda^1dp_1+\lambda^2dp_2$. If you want to show that this is true in general, you need to prove it for arbitrary dimension. Using the definition $\alpha^*\lambda=\alpha$ for a form $\alpha: M\to T^*M$, you should try and recover the expression for $\lambda$ in the canonical coordinates on $T^*M$.